Dina malchuta dina - detailed definition
Assume an observant Jew living in an area controlled by a Colombian guerilla. The guerilla is independent from (actually opposed to) the central government of the country and make their own laws.
Dina malchuta dina applies to the central government laws, or to the laws of the guerilla?
In particular, can the observant Jew partake in illegal drugs if allowed (actually encouraged, money is money) by the guerilla?

Dina dmalchuta doesn't (as far as I know) supersede other issurim- if the government tells you to carry Muktze on shabbos, you wouldn't be allowed to (much less if the govt didn't actually command you to, only encouraged you). So in regards to drugs specifically, it's probably assur just because many poskim prohibit taking drugs anyway

See Rambam Gezela 5:18. But he's discussing monetary issues so I'm not sure if this applies to legality of drugs.
